# Direct inequality proof of $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$

Tags: real-analysis

For $$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x},$$

I need to show, without using calculus, that this function obeys the property
$$x,y>0 \implies f(x+y) <f(x)+f(y).$$

It was fairly easy to do with calculus, but I don't know where to start here. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you mean $f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y).$

Comment: I do indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is pretty strait forward:
$f(x+y)=\frac{x+y}{1+x+y}=\frac{x}{1+x+y}+\frac{y}{1+x+y}\leq\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{y}{1+y}=f(x)+f(y)$
notice that the inequality is valid only because $x,y>0$.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x+y) = \dfrac {x+y}{1+x+y} = \dfrac{x}{1+x+y}+\dfrac{y}{1+x+y}$

if $x$ and $y$ are > 0 then  $1+x+y > 1+x$ and $1+x+y>1+y$

$\dfrac{x}{1+x+y} < f(x),\dfrac{y}{1+x+y} < f(y)$

Answer (score 3):

[image]

A graphic approach of the property $f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y),~x,~y>0.$